# Ensure that div is loaded before calling js function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: iam using ajax to load text in my content that is why onload on head is not applicable.

I have an almost complete project here
http://sandbox.littlegraffyx.com/bible/test2.html (enter gen 1:1 on bottom left to start)

The only problem I have is to ensure that my main div where the main text is displayed is fully loaded before I call a function that will autofit the text content on the window.

There are times that my autofit function is working and there are times it isn't and the only reason I can think of why it's not working is maybe the div isn't fully loaded yet when I call the function.

```
echo "<div id=\"verse\">" . $bcontent . "</div>";

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    scaleQuote();";
echo "</script>";
```

The scalequote sample is found in my other question here

[Adjust size based on height (vertical length)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060866/adjust-size-based-on-height-vertical-length)

Here are the searches I made and I can't see how can I apply the solutions offered in these post in my case that is why I am asking one myself. Hoping I will not be down voted for "lack of research"

[How do I  run a function only when a div gets loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242619/how-do-i-run-a-function-only-when-a-div-gets-loaded)

[getting the height and width of a div after loading info into it from an external source with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410393/getting-the-height-and-width-of-a-div-after-loading-info-into-it-from-an-externa)

thanks in advance and sorry for my english

File references

http://pastebin.com/wwQumwKJ - my JS file

http://pastebin.com/FnyST8iz - my html file

http://pastebin.com/BYfSUjQJ - my css file

Except from getting the database contents, my php file is pretty much  what is posted above.

Comment: The div **is** loaded when you execute that code, that's for sure. PHP first parses the whole script then outputs the HTML code. Your javascript function runs after the content is displayed in the page. If you think your problem is relative to page load, call your function inside the body's `onload` event - that will ensure the function is only executed when your page is fully loaded. However, I do think the problem is with your function. I'd suggest including the JS and possibly some css/html in your question as well as reproducing your problem.

Comment: If you aren't using jQuery or such, put the call to scaleQuote() in your body onload attribute. This can still be problematic, which is why it may be better to use jQuery's document ready functionality.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I have added file references. To reproduce the error. Enter 1ki 6:31 in my project textbox. press next and you will see text getting resized. press previous and it wont get resized. next and previous us calling the same php file the only difference is the argument being pass on next is + 1 and on previous -1

Comment: @CharlesWayne I've read your page's code, you're using standard JS Ajax instead of jQuery Ajax. I've submitted an answer explaining it, comment on it if you have any question. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Inside your `MovePrevious()` function, add `scaleQuote();` inside the Ajax's callback:

```
document.getElementById("versePlace").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
scaleQuote(); //<-- here
```

**Long Answer**

You're using standard JS on your Ajax calls. Standard Ajax calls such as yours, which simply places the response `HTML` inside an element with `innerHTML` does **not** execute any script tags inside of the response text. It's different than jQuery's [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)/[`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) methods, which parse any `script` tags inside of your response text and executes it upon being added to the DOM.

*Why does it work "most of the time" then?*

Because your `MoveNext()` function already has a `scaleQuote();` function call inside of its callback.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks (ffor your short answer). Regarding your long answer. does it mean I am not doing it right? I probably am because I googled most part of this project and some might not be dated. If you don't mind, can you give me a little more longer answer :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CharlesWayne, it's not that you're doing it wrong, however, you could use a little more jQuery - specifically, [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and my linked methods would provide a more readable code. Honestly, as it's working perfectly fine as it is, I don't see a need to rewrite all your code. The [`jQuery Ajax documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) may prove to be very useful for your future projects though. =]

Comment: Also, Cranio has just updated his answer with an example of how you can simplify your code with [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which is basically another shorthand to [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) passing a `GET` request with an implicit callback.

Answer (score 2):

**Complete re-edit of the answer.**
As JQuery library is already present in your page this whole bit is useless:

```
/* Function to get Requested Verse */
function showVerse(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("versePlace").innerHTML="";
... etc etc.
xmlhttp.open("GET","getverse.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Just replace it with

```
function showVerse(str)
{
    $("#versePlace").html("");
    $('#versePlace').load('getverse.php?q='+str, function() {
        scaleQuote();
    });
}
```

We are therefore moving `scaleQuote()` in a callback function.

- Reason for this: the `scaleQuote()` function is now called in the original HTML page, your first problem is that if you output a script in the AJAX result it won't be executed!
- The second main concern is to call the scaleQuote() function ONLY AFTER the AJAX request is complete. "A" in AJAX means "asynchronous", it means roughly that the caller continues its execution regardless of whether the request is completed or not.

So we must make sure to call `scaleQuote()` after the AJAX request-response has completed.

JQuery's `.load()` function calls an AJAX page and puts the result in the element in parentheses (`$("#versePlace")`, where # stands for "id"). You pass your data via GET method with an object `{q: str}` and then you define a *callback function* that is *guaranteed* to run only after the request-response thing of Ajax is completed.

Other functions can be reduced A LOT with JQuery:

```
/* Function to get Next Verse */
function MoveNext()
{
   var str = parseInt($("#txtCurrent").val()) + 1;
   if (str!="")
   {
       $("#versePlace").html("");
       $('#versePlace').load('move.php?q='+str, function() {
           scaleQuote();
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. The content is populated using ajax that is why it is not in the document ready event.

Comment: Hi cairo, sorry but you have to explain a little more because I am really new with ajax, php, and js. On your edit. are you saying that I need to call that in my html file where i called the ajax? I edited my post with file reference. I hope you don't mind if I ask you to check it and let me know where should I put this code of yours. Thanks

Comment: Edited from scratch, please check :)

Comment: Thanks for adding that. A starter like me wouldn't know a shortcut for that :) . Appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `.load` is a nice shorthand, you could add some [reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as the jQuery API site was very useful when I started learning these. I don't think OP should rewrite all his code when he has a fully working site, however this should prove to be useful in any developer's future projects. `=]`

Comment: Hi Fabricio, in this case the OP is a beginner and I think this has fair educational purposes. It's worth to show that he *already* has a powerful tool (jquery) that can *dramaticaly* reduce and ease the coding, making debugging a breeze.
Good for pointing out that a reference is useful, you're right; usually I add links, forgot this time.

Comment: I see. I think your moveNext re-write isn't fully correct though, you're executing an Ajax call when `str==""`, while in the original code `str=""` would `return;` (break) the function. I'd fix the indenting (http://jsbeautifier.org) to make it easier to read also, but that's a minor thing. One question I have though, I usually pass my `GET` query parameters as query strings, would your `{q: str}` still be accessible through the `$_GET`?

Comment: Another thing is, jQuery objects don't have a value property so `$("#txtCurrent").value` will return `undefined`. You should either use `$("#txtCurrent").val()` to retrieve the jQuery object's first element's value or `$("#txtCurrent")[0].value` or `$("#txtCurrent").get(0).value` to get the literal DOM element's `value` property (all 3 will return the same).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Right, the data object turns the request to POST. I have to correct ASAP :) I'm aware of `val()` ... sorry to both you and the OP for the distractions, now here's 5:30am and I had a sleepless night programming, hope you forgive my quirks :)

Comment: I've fixed some of your jQuery codes' indenting, even though the `str=""` seems to be doing the reverse thing. `:P`

Comment: thanks to both of you. Your comments is really helped me with this project and i will definitely consider the pointers that you both mentioned here for my future project. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is, put the function in `<head>` tags, and add that js function to `onload` property of the div.
e.g.

```
<body onload="scaleQuote()">
```

Comment: thanks for your comment and sorry that I forgot to mention I am using ajax to load text on my content. onload on body will not work